# What constitutes revelation for this Ummah?-Sunni POV

Tags: revelation

Besides Quran, Sahih Sunnah and Dreams of Prophet Jesus what other things constitute revelation for this Ummah?

Comment: Where did you see that dreams of Prophet Jesus constitute part of the revelations of Islam? And why Jesus and not any other prophet? Please include 2-3 examples of dreams of Prophet Jesus that became part of the Islamic revelations.

Comment: Search Google you will find.

Comment: You mistake true dreams are part of prophet-hood not revelation.

Comment: @sassir, Explain me how jesus abolishes jizya

Comment: That is simple by no more accepting it, this means Muslims will no more protect non-Muslims. As at this stage only Islam is accepted as a religion. (see islamqa https://islamqa.info/en/43148). But that is a totally different question.

Comment: Only Allah can change a ruling, Jesus cannot change this ruling

Comment: @III-AK-III, only eesa is going to return. His dreams will be revelation and will be applicable to this ummah. https://islamqa.info/en/6537.                        Quran 37:102. And, when he (his son) was old enough to walk with him, he said: “O my son! I have seen in a **dream** that I am slaughtering you. So look what you think!” He said: “O my father! Do that which **you are commanded**, if Allah wills, you shall find me of the patient.” ***the above verse translation is evidence that prophetic dreams are revelation***

Answer (score -1):

The question needs a correction - it should read "Dreams of Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him)" and not "Dreams of Prophet Jesus".

Basically **Quran** and **Authentic and good Hadiths** are two major revelations.
Among Authentic and good Hadiths there are categories:

- Regular Hadith
- Hadith Qudsi (direct word of Allah)
- Dreams of Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) as reported in Sahih hadith
- Revelation during meeting with Allah, at the time of his(pbuh) ascension to heaven, as reported in Sahih hadiths.

Comment: All prophetic dreams are revelation including that of Jesus. Dreams of last prophet are covered under sahih sunnah

Comment: **True dreams** (a dream that comes true as seen while "sleeping"`) are no more than a sign of Prophet-hood . Your answer also needs a correction.

Comment: As for dreams of previous prophets - they are all revelations. But for this ummah, the dreams of other prophets reach us via Quran or Hadith. We don't have direct access to their dreams via any authentic chains of narrations from that prophet.

Comment: Yes @medi1saif. Thanks for the note.

I must add this: True dream of a believer is another source of revelation. According to an authentic hadith, true dream of a believer is considered 1/46th part of prophethood.